# Error showing data with Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have this service in my Angular Project

```
getOfertas(): Observable<Oferta[]> {
return this.http.get<Oferta[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas`)
  .pipe(
    tap(data=>console.log('OfertasService-get(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

That I use in my Angular Component.ts

```
ofertas:Oferta[]=[];

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.dataService.getOfertas()
.pipe(
  tap(item=>console.log(item))
 )
.subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.ofertas=data;
    this.ofertasOriginal=this.ofertas;
  }
 )
,err=>console.log(err),
()=>{};
}
}
```

And I want to see the result in my table inside this Component.html

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
      <table class='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Id Presentada</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Organismo</th>
            <th>Fª Presentación</th>
            <th>Presupuesto</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let oferta of ofertas; let index=index">
            <td>{{oferta.id}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.idPresentada}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.descripcion}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.id}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.id}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

But I get this result in console with the data obtained from the ASP.NEt Core web API but the error showed

[image: error]

In my Web API when I debug I see this result returned.

[image: cotroller]

that is, a List of Oferta Objects

But in Angular, I get an strange object

```
{$id:
 $values:[]
}
```

But If I use this ~$values to iterate I still see nothing

```
<tr *ngFor="let oferta of ofertas.$values; let index=index">
```

If I try to assign this

[image: values]

I want to use my ofertas variable
ofertas:Oferta[]=[]

Here I have an example with the same problem; https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ymtnrw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my Web API I had to avoid the cycle object error I did it this way as explained in his blog by Felipe: https://gavilanch.wordpress.com/2021/05/19/corrigiendo-el-error-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-en-distintas-versiones-de-asp-net-core/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog

but as he himself tells me this must be the reason why now I receive the values in Angular in that object with the array in its second property, so now I have to adapt my Angular models to that structure

new model

```
import { Oferta } from './oferta';

export interface OfertaModel{
  $id:string;
  $values:Oferta[];
```

}

service.ts

```
getOfertas(): Observable<OfertaModel> {
return this.http.get<OfertaModel>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas`)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('OfertasService-getOfertas(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

component.ts

```
this.dataService.getOfertas()
.pipe(
  tap(item=>console.log(item))
)
.subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.ofertas=data.$values;
  }
)
,err=>console.log(err),
()=>{};
```

component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let oferta of ofertas; let index=index">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The response itself is not an array but contains one.

You need to change your template to

```html
<tr *ngFor="let oferta of ofertas.$values; let index=index">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know why I do not receive only the array of Ofarta instead of that strange object with $id and $values

Comment: You should ask your backend :)

Comment: Hi, my backend returns only an array of Oferta objects. And looping ofertas.$values I still don't see anything on my table

Comment: Just check your browser network tab. It shows the response very clearly.

Comment: When I debug the controller in my web API in Visual Studio I see my array of Oferta Objects clearly but when I see the browser network tab I get this another object {"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","id":"000421"...}, {}, {}}